# Steam doesn't have permission to open web links

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, steam, default-browser

I am a new Linux user, running Xubuntu 14.04, and I am trying to open an update log from Steam in my default browser i.e. Chrome. Whenever I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute default browser

Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop" (Permission denied).
```

So, if any of you could help me at all, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Steam do not support all that many browsers!
By default it uses Firefox on Linux - so install that, and your links will be opened in Firefox.

Read more in:   Ubuntu: Powerful Hacks and Customizations By Neal Krawetz

See this:
https://books.google.dk/books?id=h_zclqESvu8C&pg=PT195&lpg=PT195&dq=default+browser+in+stem&source=bl&ots=fMMfArqto7&sig=tW8vuLGUfli9ScdfNfhpznW2Zg0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh4pbDkbPKAhUGvhQKHZkBAooQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=default%20browser%20in%20stem&f=false

Comment: I am strongly against using firefox, I vastly prefer chrome.

Comment: See chapter: "Using other web-browsers" in the book mentioned.